# Getting rid of Carriage return and new line in a string

Tags: python, string

I have a string of the form

```
b'helloworld\r\n'
```

I would like to strip it of the \r\n and the the starting b. I tried using .rstrip("\n") but it crashes the system.

Comment: If `.rstrip("\n")` crashes your system, there is something *very* bad going on that most likely has little to do with Python...

Answer (score 5):

According to the Python docs, the b prefix means that your string is a byte string. Specifically:

> A prefix of 'b' or 'B' is ignored in Python 2; it indicates that the
>   literal should become a bytes literal in Python 3 (e.g. when code is
>   automatically converted with 2to3). A 'u' or 'b' prefix may be
>   followed by an 'r' prefix.

To convert this to a string without trailing newline and return, and to remove the byte prefix, you would use:

```
str(b'helloworld\r\n').rstrip('\r\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
b'helloworld\r\n'.strip() // leading + trailing
```

or

```
b'helloworld\r\n'.rstrip() // trailing only
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also decode the b-string (bytes-string), using `.decode()` and then `print()` it:

```
>>> yourBytesString = b'helloWorld\r\nnextLine\n'
>>> print(yourBytesString)
b'helloWorld\r\nnextLine\n'
>>> yourBytesString.decode()
'helloWorld\r\nnextLine\n'
>>> print(yourBytesString.decode())
helloWorld
nextLine
```

(adapted from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37813652/python-new-line-byte-to-string#comment63091445_37813652).)

Answer (score -1):

There shouldn't be any problem. Just do:

`your_string.rstrip()`

`rstrip()` without any parameters strips whitespaces, newlines and carriage returns.

Examples:

```
>>> s = 'helloworld\r\n'
>>> print s.rstrip()
helloworld


>>> s = 'helloworld             \r\n'
>>> print s.rstrip()
helloworld
```