# python new line (byte to string)

Tags: python

Code:

```
word="hello\nhai"
fout=open("sample.txt","w");
fout.write(word);
```

Output:

```
hello
hai
```

But this:

```
word=b"hello\nhai"
str_word=str(word)                     # stripping ' '(quotes) from byte
str_word=str_word[2:len(str_word)-1]   # and storing just the org word
fout=open("sample.txt","w");
fout.write(str_word);
```

Outputs:

```
hello\nhai
```

What is the problem in the code?

I am working on sending and receiving strings over a port in python. As only bytes can be sent and received I have the above problem. But why does it occur?

Comment: `str(bytes)` does not translate bytes to a string. Use `bytes.decode()` instead.

Comment: thanks a lot syntonym

Comment: @syntonym's comment should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

> I am working on sending and receiving strings over a port.  As only bytes can be sent and received I have the above problem.

`.encode()` strings to create bytes.  `.decode()` bytes to get strings.  The default encoding is UTF-8, which can handle all characters in a string.
If you have bytes, write them in binary mode:

```
word = b"hello\nhai"  # bytes
with open("sample.txt","wb") as fout:  # (w)rite (b)ytes
    fout.write(word);
```

If writing to a port that only takes bytes (you didn't mention the port function, so only an example):

```
port.write(b'hello')
```

or:

```
port.write('hello'.encode())
```

Reading:

```
string_result = port.read().decode()
```